# Matplotlib not importing correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Attempting to use matplotlib in VS Code. And it is either not importing properly or not working properly.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])

plt.ylabel('y numbers')
plt.xlabel('x numbers')

plt.show()
```

Terminal shows:

```
PS C:\Users\peter\CodingProjects\graphing> & C:/Users/peter/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe
Python 3.11.5 (tags/v3.11.5:cce6ba9, Aug 24 2023, 14:38:34) [MSC v.1936 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>  
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 56, in <module>   
    from matplotlib import _api, _cm, cbook, scale
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 22, in <module>    
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 138, in <module>  
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 49, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found.
>>> plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
>>> plt.ylabel('y numbers')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
>>> plt.xlabel('x numbers')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
>>> plt.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

I have pip installed matplotlib (seemingly successfully into project I am working in), imported it into my file as plt, and run the entire file. But it keeps telling me plt is not defined along with some other issues.

It appears as though the module is present but then acts as if it isn't.

Is this a PATH issue?

[image of my code and entire terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3fLL.png)

Comment: There's something wrong with the way it's installed, because it's getting an error when it tries to import it.

Comment: How did you install matplotlib, exactly?  Matplotlib depends on some external DLLs, and whatever you have done caused it not to find those DLLs.

Comment: I opened a powershell window in the directory of the folder I am working in VS Code, typed pip install matplotlib. Should I have done this in a different way?

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but Anaconda is not making anything easier. Do you mean to use VS Code through Anaconda or something else? I'm getting a separate issue in vs code using conda interpreter where I can't import any packages

Comment: Seems like you resolved the issue but apparently there's an extension for VSC to connect with the distribution, as per the Anaconda site. https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/ide-tutorials/python-vsc/

Answer (score 0):

on vscode terminal, run

```
 pip show matplotlib
```

this will show you `Location` property

```
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

if you navigate

```
cd /usr/lib
```

you might see multiple python versions installed:

[image]

then check the python version on vscode:

```
python --version
```

you have to make sure that `matplotlib` is installed in the current `python` version. if not, Let's say you have `python 3.10` on terminal,

```
python3.10 -m pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: I only have one version of python installed it looks like. When I search for the location of matplotlib in my VS Code terminal, it shows that it is in the site packages for python 3.11. However, even though it tells me its location, when I attempt to import it, it tells me there is a DLL load fail "The specified module could not be found

Comment: can you run `python3.11 -m pip install matplotlib` on vscode terminal and then run your code again

Comment: Did so, same issue persisting sadly

Comment: `python --version` on terminal. what does it say. is it 3.11

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by installing the Microsoft c++ distributable for VS Code. Not sure why or how this worked, saw it in a YouTube video, so if anyone cares to explain that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I have also noticed that in vs code my import statements are no longer highlighting green when they are present/active and used. Not sure if related